# Null validation not working when on a unit test

Tags: java, spring

I am currently trying to create a Unit test for a service class that I have but I am currently getting a NumberFormatException even though I already specified the parameter to throw a default value of 0 whenever it sees a value of null during getting the value of the parameter. Thing is, I already have this tested working on the actual API itself with the parameters all missing, and the variable that needs it automatically resolves it and assigns it to a value of 0 instead of null. But for some reason, during Spring Boots Unit Test task, it is still encountering an NPE.

Below is my code where Spring says that an NPE is being encountered specifically in accountingLineXYZ.getQSTAmount() code as debugging the test class showed that this one still throws a null value.

```
Long totalTaxSurchage =
    Long.valueOf(accountingLineXYZ.getQSTAmount()) + Long.valueOf(accountingLineXYZ.getQSTAmount());
```

Below is my getQSTAount() function

```
public String getQSTAmount()
    {
        if (qstAmount == null || qstAmount.isEmpty() ){
            return Constants.INITIALIZED_NUMBER.getMessage();
        } else {
            return qstAmount;
        }

    }
```

Constant class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum Constants
{
    EMPTY_STRING(""),
    INITIALIZED_NUMBER("0"),
    ONE("1");

    private String message;
}
```

Below is my Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ApplicationTests {

    @InjectMocks
    AccountingLineService accountingLineService;

    @Mock
    AccountingLine accountingLine;

    @Mock
    AccountingLineXYZ accountingLineXYZ;



    @Test
    public void testParseParameters() throws Exception {
        // Some mocks. Some of which specifically not yet created to test for the null handling of the API

        // Triggers the service that needs to be tested. 
        accountingLineService.processAccountingLine(accountingLineXYZ);

        // Is not yet reached due to the NPE on the above code.
        Assert.assertEquals(accountingLineXYZ.getId(),accountingLine.getAccountingLineID());

    }

}
```

Comment: Where did you set the behaviour for your `accountingLineXYZ` mock?

Comment: On the same accountingLineXYZ class, I already added the code snippet for the function where the supposed null validation is, its the method named getQSTAmount as this is the line of code that doesnt seem to work on a Unit Test class but working properly on the API side.

Comment: No, I mean the *mock*. You need to tell it what to do when `getQSTAmount` is called. I don't see any of that so it seems that's the reason for your NPE. A mock is a completely empty thing when you create it. You have to add behaviour yourself when using it in a test

Comment: If you need `accountingLineXYZ` to keep its original behaviour, then maybe a `@Spy` would be better instead of `@Mock`.

Comment: btw, changing the annotation from Mock to Spy indeed also allowed me to have the same behavior as my actual API. As I always received NPE with Mock annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just realized where I did wrong with regards to my test case.

So during my debug mode test case, it is erroring out a different line of code. But when testing with the actual API and changing some other fields to null, it did show the actual line of code that I missed a further NPE validation. So in my case it really is just about an issue with regards to the actual line of code that throws an NPE during unit test as it does not reliably give me the line of code that I should fix and instead points out to the line of code that already has NPE handling. I had to run the regular debug mode in my API to trace the actual line of code that causes the NPE. This may then be a bug on the JUnit library I guess or something else. Otherwise, mine was fixed thru this and also annotating all model classes that I mock with @Spy instead of @Mock . T